# Flutter: refresh data in a ListViewItem without reload ListView

Tags: flutter

i have a ListView like this.

```
 dynamic _matches = [];

 Widget _buildMatch(double statusBarPadding) {
final double boxImageSize = 200;
return BlocConsumer<MatchListCubit, MatchState>(
  listener: (context, state) {
    if (state is MatchListFetchSuccess) {
      _matches = state.matches;
    }
  },
  bloc: context.read<MatchListCubit>(),
  builder: (context, state) {
    if (state is MatchListFetchInProgress || state is MatchListIntial) {
      return Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
        Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * (0.085) + statusBarPadding + 140),
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 0, 16, 0),
            child: CircularSmallProgressContainer(
              useWhiteLoader: false,
            ))
      ]);
    }

    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * (0.085) + statusBarPadding + 140),
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 0, 16, 0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text('Matches', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Text('NEW', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: labelColor), textAlign: TextAlign.end),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
            height: boxImageSize,
            child: ListView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: _matches.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return _buildMatchCard(index, boxImageSize);
              },
            )),
      ],
    );
  },
);
```

}

I have a Widget that build the item, and it open a Timer to refresh the state of a single item.

```
Widget _buildMatchCard(index, boxImageSize) {
var current = _matches[index] as MatchQuiz;
Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 15), (Timer t) => context.read<MatchCubit>().getMatch("tomatocodes@gmail.com", current.matchID!));

return Container(
  width: boxImageSize + 10,
  child: Card(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    ),
    elevation: 2,
    color: Colors.white,
    child: GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
      onTap: () {},
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(10), topRight: Radius.circular(10)),
              child: Image.network(
                'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/h/R/4/h/i/8/dsfdsf-hi.png',
                width: 40,
                height: 40,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              )),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 8, 8, 8),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'kjbkj',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: labelColor),
                  maxLines: 2,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                  child: Text('df', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(Routes.match, arguments: {"matchModel": current});
                    },
                    child: _buildMatchCardSingle(current, boxImageSize)),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Than i put the button text that is the value i want to refresh every 15 seconds calling a WebApi, in a Bloc that return the Text with updated value,

```
 Widget _buildMatchCardSingle(MatchQuiz matchQuiz, boxImageSize) {
return BlocConsumer<MatchCubit, MatchState>(
  listener: (context, state) {
    if (state is MatchFetchSuccess) {}
  },
  bloc: context.read<MatchCubit>(),
  builder: (context, state) {
    if (state is MatchFetchSuccess) {
      return Text(((state as MatchFetchSuccess).match.opponentID != null) ? (state as MatchFetchSuccess).match.opponentID! : "Nessuno");
    } else {
      return Text(matchQuiz.opponentID!);
    }
  },
);
```

}

It update, the problem is that it update all the text with the same value even the value from the Api is correct, and it change, seems like it update with the last value every text in listview. Maybe a problem of Key?

[image]

Comment: How is the `_matches` list initialized?

Comment: I edit the build list with _matches loaded from another Bloc. _matches is defined as dynamic